# Splitting a Water Heater Gas Line to Connect Gas Dryer

Tags: appliances, gas

I have studied the following thread which gave me a lot of answers to my question.

[Split Gas Line to Gas Water Heater for Gas Dryer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/106362/split-gas-line-to-gas-water-heater-for-gas-dryer)

I still have some follow-up questions and would appreciate if someone could help me with these. I currently have a water heater connected to a gas valve in the wall. I need to split this line to connect to a gas dryer as well.

[image: Existing Gas Connection]

I am thinking of doing the following using standard connectors. Is there a better way of doing this? Also, is it OK to use Teflon sealing tape to seal the connections.

[image]

Comment: Do you know that you gas line is large enough to supply both the WH and dryer when they are burning at the same time? You can look on the specification plates on each appliance and see what the consumption is usually given in BTU/h. Gas tank water heaters usually consume 40 kBTU/h (when the burner is on). What does the dryer consume?

Comment: I suggest threading the pipe end of the fittings into the "T" , not the flare ends as shown.

Comment: The fittings in your photo are not correct for the black pipe tee. If turned around they would be ok but ONLY if you are connecting the proper flared fitting to them.  **You need a plumber because plumbing gas lines is not for someone without the proper knowledge**.

Comment: I think it's fine for amateurs to do this stuff.  **But I would NOT skip the step of putting soapy water on each connection to look for bubbles.**  And make sure you get GAS fittings and pipes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check with local code enforcement. I suspect they will want you to explain how you know your gas line will supply enough gas flow (in BTU/h) to supply both appliances simultaneously.

Then I think the code will require you to use black iron gas pipe in separate lines to individual cut off valves for each appliance. Probably you could leave the existing valve in place, use an adaptor, and place a black iron Tee there leading to two individual valves. Then at those point connect the light, flexible corrugated supply lines.

I don't think code enforcement will allow the light corrugated supply lines to have a Tee in them.

There is a special type of (yellow colored and thicker) Teflon tape for gas connections. Also there is pipe dope designed for gas connections.